# Online stock portfolio selection algorithms applicable to forex markets?

Tags: stock-market, algorithms

Are stock portfolio selection algorithms, like the [universal portfolio](http://www-isl.stanford.edu/~cover/papers/paper93.pdf) algorithm, applicable to forex markets, treating each currency like a stock?

Comment: This coul be more on topic at [Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange](http://quant.stackexchange.com/).